# Need some explanation about one line (pointers)

Tags: c

i have one little question, i try to understand a function in C and there is one line i dont understand ...
this is the code :

```
void *my_memcpy(void *dest, const void *srce, size_t n)
{   
    unsigned int size_tmp;

    size_tmp = 0;
    char *tmp_dest = dest;
    const char *tmp_srce = srce;
    while(size_tmp < n)
    {
        *tmp_dest++ = *tmp_srce++;
        size_tmp ++;
    }
    return dest;
}
```

and this is the specific line :

```
*tmp_dest++ = *tmp_srce++;
```

Thanks !

Comment: i cant edit my message to add "hello" :/

Comment: That line "copies" the value read from `tmp_srce` to `tmp_dest` then moves both pointers to the next address

Comment: OK ! thanks a lot dude !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dig out your operator precedence table, you'll notice that postfix `++` has a higher precedence than pointer *dereference*. So

`*tmp_dest++ = *tmp_srce++;`

is evaluated as

`*(tmp_dest++) = *(tmp_srce++);`

This means that the pointer `tmp_srce` is incremented by one, but the *old* pointer is dereferenced. That value is assigned to the dereferenced value of `tmp_dest`, after which that pointer too is incremented by one.

In other words, it's a cute way of copying a character from one string to another, *and* advances both pointers to the next one.

Answer (score 1):

This is a line that does several things at once:

- It takes the value pointed by the source pointer, and copies it to the address pointed to by the destination pointer
- After that, it advances both pointers by the size of data that they point to, and store their new values back into pointers, in no particular order